# Convert string pointer to string with empty string for nil

Tags: pointers, go

I have a func. that takes in two variables as string pointers, these parameters need to be passed to another func. but I need to convert the them to strings, with empty string `""` if it's a nil pointer, I have achieved this, but find my version cumbersome. How can it be simplified / prettified ?

```
func allMetricVolumes(start, end *string, measuredType []string, volumeUUID string) []*models.ResourceMetrics {
    var startStr = ""
    if start != nil {
        startStr = *start
    }

    var endStr = ""
    if end != nil {
        endStr = *end
    }

    return database.AllDataPointsMetricVolumes(startStr, endStr, measuredType, volumeUUID)
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is also an option that I came up with, just to create a helper func. but the main argument still stands though, that if it can be shorter?

```
func stringPointerToString(input *string) string {
    if input != nil {
        return *input
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you wrote it is the shortest way.

The question though why the func requires strings as pointers?

It seems that you're trying to solve the problem with optional parameters. `database.AllDataPointsMetricVolumes` function already allows an empty string. So, if you pass value instead of pointers, you can obsolete the function and use the `database.AllDataPointsMetricVolumes` directly.